# Download Ajax response as zip file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zip, blob

I am trying to download multiple images as a zip file. As I am using Azure blob, first I listed all blobs then compressed it using [Archiver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/archiver) and used pipe function to send it to the client. But I am getting zip as a raw file and it is not downloading. I am using Node js + Express. 
Server-side script:

```
    function zipURLs(urls, outStream) {
  var zipArchive = archiver.create('zip');

  async.eachLimit(urls, 3, function(url, done) {
    console.log(url);
    var stream = request.get(url);

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
      return done(err);
    }).on('end', function() {
      return done();
    });

    // Use the last part of the URL as a filename within the ZIP archive.
    zipArchive.append(stream, { name : url.replace(/^.*\//, '') });
  }, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    zipArchive.finalize();
    zipArchive.pipe(outStream);


  });
}
```

```
var data = {}; 
data.blob_name = value; 
console.log('downloading'); 
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'POST', 
    data: JSON.stringify(data),  
    contentType: 'application/json', 
    url: 'download/', 
    success: function(data) { console.log(data); }
```

Outstream is res. So I get data like this:-

[image]

How can I download directly as zip file using js?

Thanks

Comment: So how are you getting this data on the client side?

Comment: In browser... I am sending this to express js

Comment: Well I more interested in the code used in the browser to initiate the call

Comment: @Musa it's just a Ajax call to download/

Comment: Post your ajax code

Comment: var data = {};
    data.blob_name = value;
    console.log('downloading');

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: 'download/',                      
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
}

Answer (score 7):

There is a lot that goes into using ajax to download a file, first you have to be able to access the data in binary(not text which is the default) by setting the responseType to blob.
Then you have to use actually get a way to get the download dialog to show up, below you can see the anchor with download attribute technique.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url:'download/',
        type:'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),  
        contentType: 'application/json', 
        xhrFields:{
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function(data){
            var anchor = document.getElementById('a');
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            anchor.href = url.createObjectURL(data);
            anchor.download = 'archive.zip';
            document.body.append(anchor);
            anchor.click();
            setTimeout(function(){  
                document.body.removeChild(anchor);
                url.revokeObjectURL(anchor.href);
            }, 1};
        },
        error:function(){

        }
    });
```

requires jQuery3+

Comment: 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.