# PDF logged to console instead of being downloaded

Tags: node.js, ajax

My html page has a simple form which sends data via AJAX to my node app to generate a PDF with pdfkit.

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form method="POST" action="/sendPDF" id="theForm">
    <input id="userInput">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
```

ajax.js

```
$(function() {
    $('#theForm').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var userInput = $('#userInput');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/sendPDF',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ userInput: userInput.val(), }),
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                                        }
        })
    }); 
});
```

If I write the file to the server, it works fine:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
//express
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Serve the public directory
app.use(express.static('./public'))

//Return form field and handle post request
app.post('/sendPDF', (req, res) => {

    console.log("Form data: " + req.body.userInput)

// Create a PDF document
const doc = new PDFDocument();
// Use the form data
doc.text(req.body.userInput);
// Save to server
    doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));
  doc.end();
  res.end() 
})
```

However, if I try to send the file as a response to the browser, instead of downloading the file it gets sent to the browser console

```
const fs = require('fs');
const PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');
//express
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//Serve the public directory
app.use(express.static('./public'))

//Return form field and handle post request
app.post('/sendPDF', (req, res) => {

    console.log("Form data: " + req.body.userInput)

// Create a PDF document
const doc = new PDFDocument();
// Use the form data
doc.text(req.body.userInput);
// Send to browser for download
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/pdf');
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=Untitled.pdf');
doc.pipe(res);
doc.end();
})
```

Despite my best efforts for the past several hours, I can't figure out why this is happening. When the user clicks the button, I want to generate the PDF using that form data (userInput) and send it directly to the user as a download (not saving the file to the server).

UPDATE: I figured out this is related to the AJAX. By using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52101491/13915974) I managed to initiate the file download, but then the problem is that the post request doesn't forward the userInput variable (node req.body.userInput shows 'undefined').